# How to print multiple html2canvas

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I have a form with mutiple steps. However, I would like to print them separately and save. The problem is that before the html2canvas completes rendering, the info has been saved. Therefore causing the image file to be empty. Below is my code.

```
    html2canvas($('#content'), {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var all = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
            html2canvas(document.getElementsByClassName("tab")[0], {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    Student.DocumentData = canvas.toDataURL().replace(/^data[:]image\/(png|jpg|jpeg)[;]base64,/i, "");
                    Student.DocumentName = 'Student Registration Form';
                }
            })
            html2canvas(document.getElementsByClassName("tab")[1], {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    Student.DocumentData2 = canvas.toDataURL().replace(/^data[:]image\/(png|jpg|jpeg)[;]base64,/i, "");
                    Student.DocumentName2 = 'SPH Form';
                }
            })
            html2canvas(document.getElementsByClassName("tab")[2], {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    Student.DocumentData3 = canvas.toDataURL().replace(/^data[:]image\/(png|jpg|jpeg)[;]base64,/i, "");
                    Student.DocumentName3 = 'Parent Consent Form';
                }
            })
        }
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "/API/Students/",
            method: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: Student,
            dataType: "json",
            error: function (jqXHR, status, error) {
                alert(jqXHR.status + '. ' + jqXHR.statusText + '. ');
            },
            success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                var msg = "";
                for (index = 0; index < data.Message.length; ++index) {
                    msg += data.Message[index] + "\n";
                }
                alert(msg);
                if (data.StudentID !== 0) {
                    $("input[id!='btnSubmit'],select,textarea").each(function () {
                        $(this).val('');
                    });
                }
                location.reload();
            },
            complete: function (jqXHR, status) {
                $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', false);
            }
        });

    }
});
```